# How to update Object in state from e.target.name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to input data from a form like this -

```
<h1>Company Position</h1>
<input
    name="company.position"
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => functions.setData(e)}
    value={data.company.position}
/>
```

Into a state Object like this -

```
const [ form, setValues ] = useState({
    name        : 'Jo Smith',
    email       : 'JoSmith@domain.com',
    phone       : null,
    company     : {
        name     : null,
        position : null
    }
});
```

Using a handleStateChange function where I pass in the target

```
const handleStateChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

I cant seem to update the company object inside state I assumed that it would recognize company.name as the target name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target.name` is `company.position`, you can't set nested property like `obj["company.position"]`, you'll have to split it :

```
<input
  name="company.position"
  type="text"
  onChange={e => functions.setData(e)}
  value={data.company.position}
/>;

const handleStateChange = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const [section, key] = e.target.name.split(".");

  // section is : company
  // key is : position

  if (key) {
    // if you have nested keys to update
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [section]: {
        ...form[section],
        [key]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  } else {
    // if you're updating on the first level
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [section]: e.target.value
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nested = e.target.name.split(".");
    const [section, key] = nested; 
     if(nested.length > 2){
        let total = nested.length;
        let ultimo = nested[total-1];
        saveclinicHistory({
            ...clinicHistory,
            [section]: {//patient
                ...clinicHistory[section],
                [key]: {//address
                    ...clinicHistory[section][key],
                    [ultimo]:e.target.value

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work. When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it can be useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.