# React dynamic variable name with array index not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate, dynamic-variables

My dynamic variable name is not working in React.

In the constructor I define my event with:

```
this.state = {
            event: {
                location: [
                    {
                        name: 'asdfasdf',
                    }
                ],
         }
   }
```

My plan is to access the location name with the function:

```
handleChange(e) {

        const { event } = this.state
        let value = e.target.value // test
        let _key = e.target.name // location[0].name

        event[_key] = value // this.setState would be good as well
}
```

Problem: event[key] is undefined. Even just "location[0]" as "key" is undefined.
Where's my problem?

Edit:
Heres a little CodePen to play with. I created 3 handleChange functions to show what I tried so far.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/MrFlynn/pen/rNMBERQ)

Comment: Your problem is coming from the fact that `e.target.name` is a string, not JS. So its doing `event['location[0].name']`.

Comment: Hm good point...how can i solve that?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270949/how-to-update-object-in-state-from-e-target-name) gives an idea of where to start. You may find a simpler approach by function currying to get the location index, but without seeing how you render your inputs I don't know if that's feasible.

Comment: You can use eval, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval, but it is not recommend, it is up to you.

Comment: you are getting `'asdfasdf'` this in _key or `location[0].name` string?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thx for the link, ill try that.

Comment: @NishargShah i never get 'asdfasdf', i get 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mutate the state. So in your case to get that functionality with updating state you should update your code like so:

```
handleChange(e) {
  const { event } = this.state;
  let value = e.target.value;
  let _key = e.target.name;

  this.setState({ event: { ...state.event, [e.target.name]: value } });
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, but it doesn't really attempt to solve the main problem in the question.

Comment: ill create a codepen tonight or tomorrow to show it

Comment: Thanks! Will be waiting